# Understanding limits and how to interpret the meaning of "arbitrarily close"

Tags: limits, derivatives, intuition

I have read several introductory notes on limits of functions, and in all of them they introduce the notion of a limit of a function $f(x)$ by discussing what happens to the value of $f$ as $x$ approaches a given value, say $x=a$. In doing so they use phrases of the form *"if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L$ exists, this means that given a value of $x$ sufficiently close to $a$ (but not equal to $a$), we can make $f(x)$ arbitrarily close to $L$"*. What confuses me about this is, if one has the result $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L$, does this mean that one should take *"arbitrarily close"* as *"equal to"*? Is it that since arbitrarily close values of $x$ to $x=a$ lead to the value of $f$ being arbitrarily close to its value at $x=a$, we can imply that the limiting value of $f$ is exactly equal to $L$!?

The primary reason I ask is because the derivative is defined as the limit of a diffence quotient that itself is undefined at the point we are approaching, so how is one to interpret the limiting value of this difference quotient $$\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}=f'(x)$$ how can one state that its limiting value is exactly equal to the slope of the tangent line to the point $x$, equivalently the instantaneous rate of change in the value of the function $f$ with respect $x$ at the point $x$. How can we be certain that this is true?

I feel like I might have missing something important here. If anyone can enlighten me it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Two points define a line in Euclidean Geometry. The difference quotient takes the limit as the distance between the two points gets arbitrarily close to zero, where you can't really know which line to talk about.

Comment: f (x) becomes arbitrarily close to the L.  The limit does not.  The limit *is L.  Arbitrarily close refers to the individual values of f (x).  The might never be equal to L.  The tangent line is tangent at *one* point.  It takesj *two* points to find a slope.  The difference quotient is *not* the slope.  The *limit* of the difference quotient is.  The limit and the function are two different things.

Comment: @fleablood   What confuses me though, is that the limit $L$ does not have to equal the value of the function at the point we are approaching, indeed it need not even be defined at that point (as is the case of the difference quotient) so how does one know that the limit of the difference quotient is the slope of the tangent line at the limiting point? Is it simply defined that way (i.e. do we simply define the limiting value as $f'(x)$)?

Comment: @fleablood   Should one interpret $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L$ as the value that $f$ would have if we could evaluate it at $x=a$?

Comment: ... Or is it that it's the value that $f$ converges to as $x$ approaches $a$, i.e. If for whatever value of $x$ we choose, however close to $a$ we make $x$ (but not equal to), the value of $f$ gets closer and closer to the value $L$, then we can say that it's limiting value (the number that is converging to, and will eventually reach) is $L$. We symbolically write this as $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L$. Would this be correct at all?

Comment: If the function is continuous and if it were defined at a then lim x->a f(x) = f(x) but the conditions that f(x) be continuous and that it be defined are simply too specific to be generally assumed.  Your question about the tangent line is interesting.  Let me think about the best way to put it...

Comment: The thing about the slope of the tangent line is that a slope must be determined by two points.  but a tangent line intersects f(x) at just one  point.  Now for f to even *have* a tangent line at a point, a,  f(x) must be defined and continuous at a but the difference equation g(h) = [f(a+h) - f(a)]/h is obviously not defined at h=0.  But, if  f(x) is "nice", the "undefined hole" at h - 0 is a "removable singularity".  Were the function defined at h=0 and if the function were continuous it would have the value of the limit.  ...hmmm... but that begs the question

Comment: I guess this comes down to a question of mechanics.  We know that smooth curves have tangent lines but we (pre-calculus) have no mechanism to measure them.   So why do we know limits work?...  Well,  I guess because we know they can't not work.  If the slope of the tangent line were something *other* then the limit there'd be a measurable difference between the slope and the limit and we'd have an impossible case of points on a curve getting infinitely close together but their slopes getting *further* away from that of the tangent line.  ... i guess that's not very satisfying...

Comment: @fleablood     Thanks for the insightful comments. Would it be correct to say then that $f'(a)$ is the value that $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ converges to as $h$ gets closer and closer to zero. As the difference quotient is the slope of the secant line, then as $h$ approaches zero we expect that the secant line converges to the tangent line to the curve at the point $a$, and hence the limiting value of the difference quotient is the slope of the tangent line $f'(a)$. As such the derivative of the function $f$ is defined as the value that the difference value converges to as $h$ tends to 0...

Comment: Yes,  I think I would describe it like that.

Comment: ... i.e. $f'(a)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$. Is it correct to say that for a general limit say $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L$, that the value $L$ is the value that $f(x)$ is guaranteed to converge to if for a choice of $x$ close enough (but not equal) to $a$ we can make $f(x)$ arbitrarily close to the value $L$?!

Comment: ...Is the point that, in general, $f(x)$ won't ever be exactly equal to $L$, since it's value may be undefined at $x=a$, but that we can infer that it will converge to a limiting (or "boundary"), fixed value if we could hypothetically evaluate the function at $x=a$, and hence we symbolically write this value as $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L$, which is the value we expect $f(x)$ to converge to if we were we able to evaluate it exactly at $x=a$?!

Answer (score 9):

Let me be very frank here. For a beginner who is studying limits for the first time (meaning age around 16 years) the terms "sufficiently close" and "arbitrarily close" are very difficult to handle.

This is primarily because such a student at his stage of learning is acquainted mainly with algebraic simplifications/manipulations and the main focus in algebra is the operations $+,-,\times,/,=$. Thus most of the mathematical study is based on establishing equality between two expressions (via rules of common arithmetic operations).

In Calculus the symbols $+,-,\times,/,=$ take backstage and the focus shifts entirely to inequalities (but this point is never emphasized in any calculus textbook). Calculus or analysis is fundamentally based on the order relations like $<, >$ instead of arithmetical operations. Here we are not so much concerned about whether $a = b$ or not, but rather how much near / close $a$ is to $b$ when we already know that $a \neq b$. A measure of this nearness/closeness is given by the expression $|a - b|$ (which is something easily handled by students trained in algebra).

The next issue is that **students fail to comprehend the significance of the fact that there is no smallest positive rational / real number** (although students know this fact and can supply the proof very easily). Because of this fact we know that if $a \neq b$ then the expression $|a - b|$ can take whatever small positive value based on specific choice of $a, b$. Thus we can choose two distinct numbers $a$ and $b$ which are *as close to each other as we please*.

Calculus / analysis builds up on such phrases *as close to ... as we please* and introduces the terms like *sufficiently close* and *arbitrarily close* and for this purpose the very powerful notion of functional dependence is used. Thus let the numbers $a, b$ in the previous paragraph have a function dependency on some other variable. To simplify things let $a$ depend on another number $x$ via function relation $a = f(x)$ and let us keep $b$ as fixed. Thus we have a way to choose different values of $a$ by changing the value of $x$.

And then we pose the question : **How close is the value $a = f(x)$ to $b$ when the value of $x$ is close to some specific fixed number $c$?** Thus we are interested in figuring out how small the difference $|f(x) - b|$ is based on the difference $|x - c|$. If $|f(x) - b|$ is small when $|x - c|$ is small then we say that *limit of $f(x)$ is $b$ as $x \to c$*.

However to make things precise the smallness of $|f(x) - b|$ and $|x - c|$ needs to be quantified properly and when defining the concept of limit it is essential that it should be possible to *make the quantity $|f(x) - b|$ as small as we please* by choosing *$|x - c|$ to be as small as needed*. Thus the goal is to *make $|f(x) - b|$ as small as we please* and for this *making $|x - c|$ as small as needed* is a means to achieve that goal. Since the goal is primarily based on our wish (as small as we please) we say that $|f(x) - b|$ should be arbitrarily small (because our wishes are arbitrary and there is no end to supply of numbers as small as we please, remember *there is no smallest positive number*). And then once we have fixed our goal (say with some arbitrary small number $\epsilon$) we need to now choose $|x - c|$ small enough (or we say sufficiently small and quantify it with another small number $\delta$) to fulfill that goal.

And the next step is the formalism of greek symbols: *A function $f$ defined in a certain neighborhood of $c$ (but not necessarily at $c$) is said to have limit $b$ as $x$ tends to $c$, written symbolically as $\lim\limits_{x \to c}f(x) = b$, if for any arbitrarily chosen number $\epsilon > 0$ we can find a number $\delta > 0$ such that $$|f(x) - b| < \epsilon$$ whenever $0 < |x - c| < \delta$.*

Comment: So is it correct to say that the limiting value $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L$ is the value that the function value $f(x)$ converges to as the value of $x$ approaches $a$. The limit exists, if for a suitable choice of $x$ arbitrarily close to $a$, $f(x)$ is arbitrarily close in value to $L$ (the point being that we can make the value of $f$ as close as we like to $L$, for $\lvert x-a\rvert$ arbitrarily small, but not equal to zero)?!

Comment: @user35305: yes you are correct.

Comment: +1-very nice answer regarding the precise definition of limits ,but it doesn't really answer the question about derivatives per se. The key concept that's needed to make students understand the rigorous definition of limit is that of an open subset in the domain-in this case, an open interval of the real line.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see if we can make the idea of "arbitrarily close" precise and the best way to do that is by using open intervals on **R**.

To really understand this, you have to understand the precise definition of a function on it's domain. Consider the precise definition of a function: Let A and B be nonempty sets.A function F from A into B is a nonempty subset of the Cartesian product A x B = { (a,b) ={a,{a,b}| a is in A and b is in B} where no 2 different ordered pairs have the same first member. The set of all first members of the function is called the domain of the function and the set of all second members of the function is called the range of f. Therefore, a function is not defined at a point a in A iff there is no such ordered pair in f where f(a) = z where z is in the range of f.

A limit of a real valued function,however, is defined by open interval (a,b) in the real line R of the domain and a corresponding open subset of the range (c,d)= (f(a).d) such that if |a-b| < r where r is some positive real number, then there exists some positive real number r' such that |c -d|< r'. This is certainly true even if d is not in the range of f.

If you understand this,then applying this to the limit of the difference quotient at a specific point x in **R** is pretty straightforward even without the geometric definition of the derivative. If a line L is tangent to the given point x, then it's not hard to see that all the points "near" x on L lie within some open ball in the plane or some open interval of the real line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not really sure I fully understand it though. Is the point that arbitrarily close values of $x$ to a given point with lie on the line tangent to that point and therefore by making $x$ arbitrarily close to that point we can guarantee that the limiting value of $f$ (as $x$ approaches that point) is equal to the value $f'(x)$, i.e. the slope of the tangent line at that point?!

Comment: Yes,basically. It means all values of the difference quotient lie within some open ball of f'(x) in the plane when all of the values of the absolute value of dx. A good discussion with animations relating the secant lines to the definition of the derivative can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative

Comment: So the limit is a value that the function values converge to as we make its input arbitrarily close to a particular point, right? Is the intuition behind the limit that, supposing we can't evaluate a function at a particular point $x=a$, we can still infer that it converges to a particular value as we approach $x=a$. This is true if, as we choose values of $x$ increasingly close to $x=a$, the values of the function converge to a particular value....

Comment: ... As the function values get closer and closer to this particular value as $x$ gets closer to $a$, we can say that the limiting value of the function is $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$. Is this why we call it a limit, since it is a value that the function will converge to as $\lvert x-a\rvert$ is made arbitrarily small? Would it be correct to say that the derivative of a function $f$ is a function $f'$ whose value at a point $x$ is equal to the limiting value of the difference quotient, i.e. $f'(x)=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$?!

Answer (score 1):

Let me be very frank here.  The reason this appears to be complicated in the other answers is because they are working with long-winded paraphrases of shorter and clearer infinitesimal definitions.

The dirty secret here is that the limit as $x$ tends to $c$ is the standard part when $x$ is infinitely close to $c$.  For example a formula like $f'(x)=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$ *means* that one takes the standard part of the ratio $\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$ when $\Delta x$ is *infinitesimal*. To be more specific, if $y=f(x)=x^2$ then one forms the ratio $\Delta y/\Delta x$ resulting in $2x+\Delta x$.  Then one takes standard part, obtaining $f'(x)=\text{st}(2x+\Delta x)=2x$.  That's all there is too it.

For more details see Keisler's [*Elementary Calculus*](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html).