# Function $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x) = L$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, proof-verification

If $f$ is a function then
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$$

implies that $f(x)$ gets closer to $L$ as $x$ gets closer to $a$.

Is this right?

Comment: Well, I would rather use the verb 'means' in place of 'implies', but yes, at least in a small neighborhood of $a$. And this intuitive meaning has a precise definition.

Comment: In broad strokes that is the idea, but it is not a rigorous definition.  It is good enough to get you through a first year calculus class, but If you go on to take real analysis, you will need to more thoroughly understand a more precise definition.

Comment: You can improve your idea of limit by saying that *values of $f$ can be ensured to lie as near to $L$ as we please for all values of $x$ which lie sufficiently close to $a$*.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You could add an answer on this!

Comment: @gimusi : I have written about this in past. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1324644/72031

Comment: @gimusi : and another one here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1733170/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks a lot!

Comment: @stadigfora Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

That is what it means, yes.

And even better: $f(x)$ can come *arbitrarily close* to $L$ as $x$ gets closer to $a$. This is a subtle, but important difference: $\cos(x)$ gets closer and closer to $2$ as $x$ gets closer to $0$, but you can never actually get really close to $2$. So $\lim_{x\to0}\cos(x)$ isn't $2$.

Also important: as $x$ gets closer to $a$, $f(x)$ not only gets close to $L$, but it gets close to $L$ for *all* values of $x$ close to $a$. For instance, $\sin(1/x)$ gets close to $0$ as $x$ gets close to $0$, but it is also far away for some $x$ close to $0$ as well. So $\lim_{x\to0}\sin(1/x)$ isn't $0$.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: +1 to compensate for the downvote. The last paragraph could be worded as "$f(x)$ should get close to $L$ for *all* values of $x$ close to $a$".

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is the naive idea for the definition of limit for which get closer means "*get eventually and arbitrarly closer*" with respect to any prescribed bound but not necessarly equal to the limit and not necessarly monotonically, that is formally

$$\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = L\right) \iff \Big(\forall \varepsilon >0\, \exists \delta > 0: \big(0<\vert x-a\vert <\delta \implies \vert f(x)-L\vert <\varepsilon\big)\Big)$$

Comment: Thus the official definition od limit is wrong? That's good to know! We never end to learn!

Comment: I initially downvoted because to me "[eventually] $f(x)$ gets close to $L$ as $x$ gets close to $a$" does not imply "[eventually] $f(x)$ gets closer to $L$ as $x$ gets closer to $a$". But in retrospect, this language is ambiguous, so I reversed.

Comment: @KBDave Thanks for your comment, indeed it is not possible to guess what exactly the asker has in his mind and what he means exactly for "get closer", anyway the aswers given here will give to him/her a nice and complete overview that the naive "get closer" idea has behind more complex concepts which require a rigorous definition.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks! indeed it is often a matter of great confusion.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ if }x=0\end{cases}$$Then $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$. However, no matter how close you are to $0$, there are points $x$ at which $f(x)=0$ and there are points $x$ at which $f(x)\neq0$.

Comment: ok there are points at which f(x)=0 but we get closer according to the definition of limit, I don't understand the initial "No" in the answer. Could you please explain? Thanks

Comment: @gimusi We *don't* get closer and closer. When $x=\frac1\pi$, $f(x)=0$. So, we couldn't possibly get closer to $0$ than that. But after that, as $x$ approaches $0$, we actually get **away** from $0$, and then we get again closer to $0$, reaching it again when $x=\frac1{2\pi}$. And then we get again away from $0$. And so on.

Comment: Yes of course but, as we know, we can get arbitrarly and eventually closer as we want thus the initial "No" in your answer seems a little bit stringent to me since it depends upon what the asker mean with the term "get closer".

Comment: There is no $\delta>0$ such that, for all $\lvert x \rvert<\delta$, $\lvert f(x)\rvert$ decreases as  $\lvert x\rvert$ decreases, even though for all $\delta>0$, $\max_{\lvert x\rvert \in[0,\delta]}\lvert f(x)\rvert$ decreases as $\delta$ decreases.

Comment: @gimusi Let us wait for the comments by the OP.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ok, meanwhile note that the OP doesn't state "gets closer and closer" but simply "get closer" that is just the definition of limit, by the way the definition of limit that I know.