# What is the difference between "arbitrarily close" and "sufficiently close" in term of limits?

Tags: calculus, limits, terminology

The definition of limit as always

> “the limit of $f(x)$, as $x$ approaches $a$, equals $L$” means we can
>   make the values of $f(x)$ arbitrarily close to $L$ by restricting x to
>   be sufficiently close to $a$ but not equal to $a$.

What exactly mean by phrases "arbitrarily close" for $f(x)$ and "sufficiently close" for $x$ ? Are they interchangeable ?

Comment: Teh closedness in sufficiently close depends on the one in arbitrarily close.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1733170/72031

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the limit of $f(x)$, as $x$ approaches $a$, equals $L$” means we can
>   make the values of $f(x)$ **arbitrarily close** to $L$

Rephrasing: "*as close as we want*"

> by restricting x to be **sufficiently close** to $a$ but not equal to $a$.

Rephrasing: "*close enough*"

---

Or put differently: $L$ is the limit (as $x$ approaches $a$) if we can

- make the *distance* from $f(x)$ to $L$ **as small as we want**,
- by only making the *distance* from $x$ to $a$ **small enough**.

Comment: Is there something wrong with this answer? If the down voter cares to explain, perhaps I can improve it.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suggest replacing "only by" (suggesting "this is the only way") with "by only" (suggesting "using this as our only tool to achieve the desired effect, even though there could be other ways").

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset Thanks, that's better indeed.

Answer (score 2):

- arbitrarily close: true for *any* closeness, how large or how small; $\forall\epsilon$.

$|x-1|>0$ holds for $x$ arbitrarily close to $1$.

- sufficiently close: true under some suitable upper bound; $\forall\epsilon<u$ where $u$ is dictated by the problem on hand.

$|x-1|<1$ holds for $x$ sufficiently close to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

You do not mention where your function $f$ is defined and which range it has, but let us assume that it is a function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Your definition

"We can make the values of $f(x)$ arbitrarily close to $L$ by restricting $x$ to be sufficiently close to $a$ but not equal to $a$"

of the limit of $f$ is nothing else than a verbal rephrasing of the standard $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-definition. **Arbitraritly close** means that **for each** $\varepsilon > 0$, how big or small it may be, you get

$\lvert f(x) - L  \rvert <  \varepsilon$ by restricting $x$ to be sufficiently close to $a$ but not equal to $a$.

**Sufficiently close** means that **there exists** some $\delta > 0$ such that

$\lvert f(x) - L  \rvert <  \varepsilon$ for all $x \ne a$ with $\lvert x - a \rvert < \delta$.

Thus "arbitraritly close to $L$" means "for all neighborhoods of $L$" and "sufficiently close to $a$" means "there exists a neighborhood of $a$".

You see that this is not interchangeable.

Comment: if $f(x)$ is fixed from $L$ by specific number isn't this indicate that the limit exist also ?

Comment: If this condition is satisfied, then the limit exists and is equal to $L$.